# Is there a way to export create-react-app to a static app that includes all API/DB data?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, static-pages, jamstack

I have page X, which has to make DB and API calls taking approximately three seconds. I want to export this as a single page that integrates all of the data that comes in from the network, this means that there is no need to load from DB when displaying this new page.

I have a feeling it has to do with Webpack, or [react-static](https://github.com/react-static/react-static) but am not sure. It needs to take the final rendered page, and save that as a page in itself, removing the need for any DB calls.

Comment: I think what you want is server-side rendering. This way the page can load with all the data pre-filled. That said, the data will have to come from somewhere and on your server-side you'll still be making DB calls - they just won't happen in the form of ajax calls from the client-side.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid ajax calls and DB calls altogether, so will continue looking for a solution to export as a static page